# Register RequestContext in Application_start (global.asax)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, autofac

I'm trying to register RequestContext for my IoC container (autofac). I do all the registration in Application_start.

The RequestContext registration looks like this:

```
builder.Register(x => HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext).As<RequestContext>();
```

this works fine on the dev webserver but in IIS 7 (integrated mode) the problem is that RequestContext context is not available in Application_start.

What can I do here ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears there are two problems to be solved here:

1. How do you register RequestContext?
2. Why isn't RequestContext properly resolving?

The easiest thing you can do for registration if you're using the Autofac MVC integration is:

```
builder.RegisterModule<AutofacWebTypesModule>();
```

There is already a module that registers the various web abstractions (HttpContextBase, RequestContext, etc.) properly scoped to instance-per-HTTP-request. It's tested and will save you a lot of time.

If, instead, you want to register it manually yourself, doing what you have should work if you scope it to InstancePerHttpRequest (that way you don't get it over and over on each request).

Additionally, you can "chain" it into the current context like in the module:

```
builder.Register(c => new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current))
    .As<HttpContextBase>()
    .InstancePerHttpRequest();
builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<HttpRequestBase>().RequestContext)
    .As<RequestContext>()
    .InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

That takes care of the first part, but the second part is sort of tricky.

If you're getting errors at app startup because the RequestContext isn't available, then **somewhere in your app you're trying to resolve something that uses RequestContext before you actually have a request.** For example, an HttpModule implementation that is manually trying to resolve something that has RequestContext as a constructor parameter.

The lambda in the registration doesn't actually get evaluated until resolution, so the error is probably coming from something you're resolving that is trying to consume RequestContext too early.

In that case, the question is: **How do you want to handle resolution when you try to resolve RequestContext and there's no request?**

By default, you'll get an exception, which is probably what you're seeing now.

If you want it to be null instead, then do a registration like this:

```
// Register context as instance-per-dependency and handle the
// case where it's null. Also handle HttpException because IIS7
// can throw if you access HttpContext.Current too soon in app startup.
builder.Register(
  c => {
    try
    {
      var ctx = HttpContext.Current;
      return ctx == null ? null : new HttpContextWrapper(ctx);
    }
    catch(HttpException)
    {
      return null;
    }
  }).As<HttpContextBase>();

// RequestContext also gets registered instance-per-dependency
// and handles the null context case.
builder.Register(
  c => {
    var ctx = c.Resolve<HttpRequestBase>();
    return ctx == null ? null : ctx.RequestContext;
  }).As<RequestContext>();
```

That should get you past the app-startup problem.

All that said... **you should figure out what's trying to use RequestContext at application startup and see if you can fix the design**. You shouldn't end up needing to do this sort of thing in normal circumstances.